# looking for a c++ socket dll to use in c#

Tags: c#, c++, sockets, dll

I want to write a c# program that create a socket using a native socket dll witch is would be written in c or c++

any idea about a good c++ socket dll ?

Comment: Any reason you're not using the classes in the [System.Net.Sockets Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.aspx)?

Comment: Can you clarify the purpose of this extra layer of abstraction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this yourself using direct PInvoke on the [Winsock API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740673%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), which is all wrapped up in a system DLL.

The question is, why would you want to?  Unless the hypothetical DLL has some added value that's not clear in the question, can't think why using `System.Net` is not infinitely preferable.

Comment: sure thing but I have to...

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, but good luck.

Comment: @mehdouch : "Have to" means it's homework?

Comment: @Henk Holterman : kind of practice in order to resolve a client issue.